# Alphanumeric array sorting identical to JavaScript function localecompare()

Tags: javascript, php, sorting, multidimensional-array, locale

I am struggling with alphanumeric array sorting, I have below array and I the result identical to the result of JavaScript sorting function `localecompare()` below is my code:

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
        array( 'label' => '#C' ),
        array( 'label' => '!A' ),
        array( 'label' => '@B' ),
        array( 'label' => 'g' ),
        array( 'label' => '98' ),
        array( 'label' => 'G' )
    );

    usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcasecmp($a['label'], $b['label']);
    });

    print_r($arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [label] => !A )
    [1] => Array ( [label] => #C )
    [2] => Array ( [label] => 98 )
    [3] => Array ( [label] => @B )
    [4] => Array ( [label] => g )
    [5] => Array ( [label] => G )
)
```

But I am trying to achieve the result as below which is equivalent to the result of JavaScript sorting function `localecompare()`

**Expected:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array ( [label] => !A )    
    [1] => Array ( [label] => @B )    
    [2] => Array ( [label] => #C )
    [3] => Array ( [label] => 98 )    
    [4] => Array ( [label] => g )    
    [5] => Array ( [label] => G )    
)
```

Comment: Great thanks to you but yes went through that question which is not solved 
 and marked also not working in my case thanks again

Comment: There are more in the link above. Let me know if you could not solve it and why, then I can re-open